# Checking health of Kafka Stream Threads

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When some of the stream threads die (because of an exception for example), I don't want to continue, but restart the process.

In order to do this, I need to identify this state.

I know I can use `kafkaStream.state()`, but it checks the state of the whole kstreams. Meaning if only one StreamThread has died, it will not be discovered by `kafkaStream.state()`.

What is the best way for me to know in the code that all StreamThreads are alive and working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** : adding timeout to `KafkaStreams#close()` as it can cause deadlock as Matthias stated [in the comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4366)

If you want to detect if any StreamThreads has dies then you can use `KafkaStreams#setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`, you can stop streaming and exit app:

```
kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
    logger.error("Exiting ", e);
    kafkaStreams.close(10);
    System.exit(1);//exit with error code so container can restart this app
});
```

Comment: You should not call `close()` without timeout in the handler! It might result in a deadlock (Cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4366)